# Use two fields in a record to define a third field in a record

Tags: ocaml

Can you use two fields in a record to define a third field? For instance

```
type  t = { a : int; b : int; c : int } 
{ a = 1 ; b = 2; c = a * b};
```

or even better

```
type t = { a : int; b : int; c = a * b }
```

Or something to that affect in Ocaml? I know you could easily write a function to compute c, instead of having it stored inside of a field.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Neither of your proposed syntaxes works in OCaml as we have it today.

You can write a function to construct a record:

```
# let mkt a b = { a; b; c = a * b };;
val mkt : int -> int -> t = <fun>
# mkt 2 3;;
- : t = {a = 2; b = 3; c = 6}
```

You could use an object type, so that `c` is computed on demand:

```
# class c a b = object method a = a method b = b method c = a * b end;;
class c :
  int -> int -> object method a : int method b : int method c : int end
# let x = new c 3 4;;
val x : c = <obj>
# (x#a, x#b, x#c);;
- : int * int * int = (3, 4, 12)
```

That's the best I can come up with.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to make sure that every `t` is created with a particular meaning for a field, you can use the module system. `private` types will allow others to access the field while disallowing direct creation (or mutation, it there are mutable parts) of a `t`.

It looks like this:

```
module Foo : sig
  type t = private { a : int; b : int; c : int }
  val create : int -> int -> t
end = struct
  type t = { a : int; b : int; c : int }
  let create a b = { a; b; c = a * b; }
end
```

This is a very effective way to enforce an invariant, but it might be a bit heavy.

Answer (score 1):

Exists 1 ineffective way.

Let's look at Haskell code:

```
data Rec = Rec {a::Int, b::Int, c::Int}

d = Rec {a = 2, b = 3, c = a d * b d}

> d
Rec {a = 2, b = 3, c = 6}
```

So, to simulate same in OCaml we must change a bit type:

```
type  t = { a : int; b : int; c : int lazy_t} 

> let rec d = {a = 2; b = 3; c = lazy (d.a * d.b)};;
val d : t = {a = 2; b = 3; c = <lazy>}

> Lazy.force d.c;;
- : int = 6

> d
- : t = {a = 2; b = 3; c = lazy 6}
```